# Cannot seem to get JSON data from an API that I have built on another server and display it to the screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I have built an API using Node, MongoDB and JavaScript. It is working perfectly. I can GET, PUT, POST and DELETE JSON data. My issue arises when I try to do these things from the front end of my application which I am building on another server. Both the of the servers that I have mentioned are localhost but on different ports which is why I cannot provide links to them. I am using React as my front end framework with JavaScript.

Here is the code for my index.html file on the front end:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React Application Learning</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="list-wrapper"></div>

    <script src="/app/bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#button').on('click', function(){
            document.write('Button Pressed');

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/organisations',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    var text = '';
                    var len = data.length;
                    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                        dataSet = data[i];
                        text += '<p>' + dataSet['text'] + '</p>'                           
                    }
                    document.write(text);
                    console.log(text);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Here is my index.js file containing the `ListComponent`:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

//creating a component
var ListComponent = React.createClass({

    render: function(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Home Page</h1>
                <p>This is the list component</p>
                <button id="button">Add Student</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<ListComponent/>, document.getElementById('list-wrapper'));
```

After clicking the Add Student button the document is as follows:

> Button Pressed
> undefined
> undefined

The console however does suggest that I have received the JSON data correctly as it shows me the two objects that have been returned.

This makes me believe that there is an error with the format or type of the data which will not allow me to display it as it says that it is undefined.

I may be processing this data wrong when trying to serve it to the user?
Any advice on how this data can be correctly displayed to the user would be of great use.

I would also be lost when it comes to using the API to POST, DELETE or PUT data.

I do not want my question to be any more general but any advice on how to interact with the API in a clean and effective manner when they are situated on different servers using JavaScript would be of create use.

Comment: have you tried to check the network tab on the console to see if you are getting the data on the ajax request?

Comment: What do you get in your first `console.log(data)`

Comment: rule - I have this organisations?callback=jQuery1124025667076357069973_1481813873101&_=1481813873102 with a status of 200

Comment: @George I got all of the json data that I was looking for. The two objects. But I am unsure why it is not writing them to the document instead of the two <p>undefined</p> paragraphs

Comment: What does that data look like though, can you post it here (if it's confidential just change the values)

Comment: @George Array[2]
0
:
Object
_id
:
"5844636833539c2d75a1da0c"
location
:
"location"
name
:
"name"
type
:
Array[2]
0
:
"type"
1
:
"type2"
length
:
2

Comment: That is one of the objects without the _proto_ things as they are too big

Comment: Your issue is that the objects don't have a property called 'text'

Comment: your dataSet['text'] might be an issue, cant see that property on the info that you showed

Comment: @George so it seems that my issue is not getting the data but serving it to the user appears to be the issue. I should imagine that I am at fault where I have tried to arrange the data into <p> tags

Comment: Sort of, your object looks like this (We'll just look at the first one) `{location:"location", name:"name"}` you're trying to access the property called `text`, this is not a property of this object. Hence why you're getting undefined.

Comment: If I do document.write(data) then I get the two objects displayed to the document but they are not showing all of the data. I receive undefined if I use data.location for example?

Comment: Yes that's because data is an array, do data[0].location

Comment: Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you are doing this line of code:

```
text += '<p>' + dataSet['text'] + '</p>'
```

You're trying to access the property `text` of the object `dataSet`. This does not exist on either objects so it will return undefined.

If you changed it to

```
text += '<p>' + dataSet['name'] + '</p>'
```

You'll see you'll get `name undefined` output